# How to overlay a fabric pattern on a Seat Image to make it look authentic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, overlay, distort

I need your expert advice. My goal is to use pattern overlay correctly on a seat image. I googled for several options and I tried a couple tutorials. So far, the Filter | Distort | Displace seems likely the answer. However, is there a better way to wrap the pattern over the seat seamlessly that it looks like the original fabric?

I started with this original image. It's poor quality and low res.
[image: Original Image]

With this pattern, i re-sized it smaller to almost the actual size [image: Fabric Pattern],

I used Content Aware to create a pattern layer that can cover the seat, which is this [image: Pattern Created]

After which, I created a Displacement Map with the first image (original image). Then I used the Filter | Distort | Displace; using the standard values of 10 for both.

Here's the screenshot of it.

[image: Displace values]

This is my final output, I just added a Blending Mode of Multiply like 45%
[image] Please Open image in new tab and zoom for 100% as it's a huge image.

Do you guys have a better suggestion on how do to this properly? The goal is to make it unnoticeable that it’s photoshopped.

Thank you!

S.

Comment: Perhaps distort certain portions to be less homogenous. One of the biggest is the the patterns is laid flat on it rather then it looking like in was wrapped around an object.

Comment: Great suggestion. I took note that I shouldn't just lay it flat, and make efforts sort of show some digital artifacts, dents and slightly varying texture (e. g., headrests, corners, sides, etc). Together with other suggestions, I made more distortions with Puppet Warp. I like the way it now wraps over my headrests and over the seat itself! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

- First use a mesh-based distortion like `Puppet Warp`, `Liquify`. Though if you have access to Illustrator, I think its `Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` may be the best way to wrap a texture easily.
- Separate each item to its own layer. You'll avoid a lot of unnecessary stretching that way.
- Use `Displace` at the very end to sell the creases, not make major distortions. You'll want to create a real displacement map instead of using the original image. For a quick and dirty version, use `Stylize > Emboss`, then blur the result.

Comment: I have a question about Envelope Distort, how can i use the two .pngs. I found this sample graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/… but seems not working for me as I am working with 2 .pngs. Thanks –

Comment: There's no simple way to do this with two raster files. In the post which you just linked, the shape acting as a displacement map is a vector shape, not a raster image. To boot, their answer also uses Illustrator.

Comment: Yeah, I was googling for more information about Envelope Distort. However, I forgot to mention that your other suggestion of using Puppet Warp works great. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I'd also suggest using a different blending mode. `Soft light` will give you a better result.